# GLSURFACEVIEW SAVE to PNG - ERROR glReadPixels

Tags: android, dalvik, glsurfaceview, glreadpixels

I am trying to render the output of a glsurfaceview to a PNG on the sdCard and am having some  issues. I have spent a few days trying to sort through similar SO queries and this is simply above my level of expertise. Can someone pls help me sort thru the Logs below and see where I might be going wrong.

Many thanks.

Log:

```
12-16 12:09:18.831: E/AndroidRuntime(29864): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 2712
12-16 12:09:18.831: E/AndroidRuntime(29864): java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
12-16 12:09:18.831: E/AndroidRuntime(29864):    at java.nio.Buffer.checkGetBounds(Buffer.java:177)
12-16 12:09:18.831: E/AndroidRuntime(29864):    at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.get(DirectByteBuffer.java:66)
12-16 12:09:18.831: E/AndroidRuntime(29864):    at java.nio.IntToByteBufferAdapter.get(IntToByteBufferAdapter.java:105)
12-16 12:09:18.831: E/AndroidRuntime(29864):    at java.nio.IntBuffer.get(IntBuffer.java:234)
12-16 12:09:18.831: E/AndroidRuntime(29864):    at com.research.glgrade.GLLayer.grabPixels(GLLayer.java:865)
12-16 12:09:18.831: E/AndroidRuntime(29864):    at com.research.glgrade.GLLayer.saveScreenShot(GLLayer.java:810)
12-16 12:09:18.831: E/AndroidRuntime(29864):    at com.research.glgrade.GLLayer.onDrawFrame(GLLayer.java:794)
12-16 12:09:18.831: E/AndroidRuntime(29864):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1527)
12-16 12:09:18.831: E/AndroidRuntime(29864):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
12-16 12:09:26.849: I/Choreographer(29864): Skipped 478 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Here is my current code:
From Main Activity :

```
GlobalVariables.setPrint("true");
mView.requestRender();
```

From Render Class

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused ) {
GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    final String vertexShader = getVertexShader();
    final String fragmentShader = getFragmentShader();

    final int vertexShaderHandle = ShaderHelper.compileShader(
            GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);
    final int fragmentShaderHandle = ShaderHelper.compileShader(
            GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);

    mProgramHandle = ShaderHelper.createAndLinkProgram(vertexShaderHandle,
            fragmentShaderHandle, new String[] { "a_Position",
                    "a_TexCoordinate" });

    // Set our per-vertex lighting program.
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgramHandle);
            // Set program handles for cube drawing. 
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle,
            "u_MVPMatrix");
    mTextureUniformHandle0 = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle,
            "u_Texture0");
    mTextureUniformHandle1 = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle,
            "u_Texture1");

            GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE4);
            // Bind the texture to this unit.
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureDataHandle4);
            // Tell the texture uniform sampler to use this texture in the shader by
            // binding to texture unit 3.
    GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle4, 4);


    // Draw some cubes.
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);


    Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, mTransX, mTransY, mAngle*0.05f);
    Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    drawCube();   


    int width_surfacea =  width_surface ;
        int height_surfacea = height_surface ;

    if ( GlobalVariables.getPrint() != "false" ) {

        String mFrameCount = "1";
        saveScreenShot(0, 0, width_surfacea, height_surfacea, "/save/test.png");
        GlobalVariables.setPrint("false");


    }

}

    public void saveScreenShot(int x, int y, int w, int h, String filename) {

    Bitmap bmp = grabPixels(x, y, w, h);

    try {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + filename;

        File file = new File(path);
        file.createNewFile();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);

        fos.flush();

        fos.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Bitmap grabPixels(int x, int y, int w, int h) {

    int screenshotSize = w * h;

    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(screenshotSize * 3);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    bb.position(0);
    GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GLES20.GL_RGB, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb);
    int pixelsBuffer[] = new int[screenshotSize];

    bb.asIntBuffer().get(pixelsBuffer);
    bb = null;

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

    bitmap.setPixels(pixelsBuffer, screenshotSize-w, -w, 0, 0, w, h);

    pixelsBuffer = null;

    short sBuffer[] = new short[screenshotSize];
    ShortBuffer sb = ShortBuffer.wrap(sBuffer);
    bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(sb);

    //Making created bitmap (from OpenGL points) compatible with Android bitmap
    for (int i = 0; i < screenshotSize; ++i) {                  
        short v = sBuffer[i];
        sBuffer[i] = (short) (((v&0x1f) << 11) | (v&0x7e0) | ((v&0xf800) >> 11));
    }
    sb.rewind();
    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(sb);


    return bitmap;

}
```

Comment: when you chose a GL context, what pixel format did you choose?

Comment: in my Main Activity onCreate defines mView as mView.setZOrderOnTop(false);
        mView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mView.setRenderer(new GLLayer(this));
        mView.setDebugFlags(GLSurfaceView.DEBUG_CHECK_GL_ERROR);
        //mView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
        mView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);

Comment: There is no specific Color definition for the GLSurfaceview.

Comment: Line 865    bb = null;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have array length mismatch.
The line of code:

```
 bb.asIntBuffer().get(pixelsBuffer);
```

Causes an exception because the length of bb.asIntBuffer() is only (w*h*3) while the length of pixelsBuffer is w*h*4 (of course I am speaking about bytes).
So the get() throws an exception as it should (according to the docs)
[http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/IntBuffer.html#get%28int[]%29](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/IntBuffer.html#get%28int%5B%5D%29)

Update:

Try this code (warning: I haven't even try to compile it):

```
public Bitmap grabPixels(int x, int y, int w, int h) {

    // Allocate byte array of H*W size assuming that we retrieve only R,G and B values
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(screenshotSize * 3);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    byteBuffer.position(0);
    // Read RGB values to our byte array
    GLES20.glReadPixels(x, y, w, h, GLES20.GL_RGB, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, byteBuffer);

    //Now we need to convert the 24bit RGB data to ARGB8888 format
    // I like arrays, they are honest :)
    byte[] pixelBuffer = byteBuffer.array();
    // This is an array that we going to use as backend for the bitmap
    int[] finalPixels = new int[w*h];
    // Let the magic flow
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < pixelBuffer.length; i += 3) {
        byte red = pixelBuffer[i];
        byte green = pixelBuffer[i+1];
        byte blue = pixelBuffer[i+2];

        finalPixels[j++] = 0xFF000000 | ((int)blue << 16) | ((int)green << 8) | red; 
    }

    // Create a bitmap of ARGB_8888
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(finalPixels, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. I changed bb to BYteBuffer.allocateDirect(screenshotSize * 4) which now run the process without crashing but the resultant PNG is BLACK.

Comment: Hi Alex I added your changes and the code runs smoothly but the resultant image is still Black. Is it because the glReadPixels is prefixed GLES20? How can I check if what is feeding ReadPixels has my on-screen images?

Comment: This Worked after I matched the EGLConfigChooser to 8888.

Comment: @user1540142 : can you please post the solution ?

Comment: @Anukool My guess is that the code, that I posted in the answer works if you use ARGB8888 pixel format when configuring the GLView. So, the last comment from user1540142 suggests. I think the full solution would be to use this config chooser setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0); when initializing the view and then the code I provided to do the color conversion.

Comment: exactly as alex suggests above worked for me. It was having to add the setEGLConfigChooser(8,8,8,8,16,0). Prior to this inclusion I rendered black stills.

Answer (score 2):

Sample code for extracting frames from an MPEG file can be found [on bigflake](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#ExtractMpegFramesTest).  The video frames are rendered with GL, and the `saveFrame()` function uses `glReadPixels()` and `Bitmap` to save it to disk as a PNG.

There are some fairly significant performance pitfalls that you need to be aware of; see comments in `saveFrame()` for some notes about how best to use NIO.  You'll also want to make sure your EGLConfig matches your pixel read format (`glReadPixels()` may get very slow if the source and destination formats aren't the same).

**Update:** there's now a slightly more general implementation in Grafika -- see [EglSurfaceBase#saveFrame()](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/b1df331e89cffeab621f02b102d4c2c25eb6088a/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/gles/EglSurfaceBase.java#L157).

Comment: Grafika link is broken. Updated link: https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/gles/EglSurfaceBase.java

Comment: @DaveNottage: updated with github "permalink".

Answer (score 1):

I think `ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(screenshotSize * 3);` is wrong. 
It should be `ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(screenshotSize * 4);`

Comment: THanks Shashika. Changing it to * 4 now saves the PNG without crashing but it is BLACK.

Comment: I would suggest two more changes.     GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb); and Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Comment: Something is definitely wrong here.  If I make both changes I get "stack corruption detected  aborted". Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure why are you doing bit shifting operations. May be you can comment out that code now, since we use ARGB_8888.